# How to use std::iterator with basic type uint8_t*?

Tags: c++, iterator, bitcoin

In Bitcoin Core C++ implementation there is the [code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/uint256.cpp#L23) that traverses array of uint8_t using `std::reverse_iterator<const uint8_t*>`.

See the simplified code below and also in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2vVGpUFZ).

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
uint8_t data[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

template<typename T>
void HexStr(const T itbegin, const T itend)
{
    for (T it = itbegin; it < itend; ++it)
    {
        cout << +*it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    HexStr(reverse_iterator<const uint8_t*>(data + sizeof(data)),
           reverse_iterator<const uint8_t*>(data));

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why the same *cannot* be done using a regular iterator (`std::iterator<const uint8_t*>`) - the compiler error is `error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)`.

See the failing code in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gwYbDGgv).

The code can be copied and compiled online here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: Please post the code as a [mcve], not as links to some pastebin sites nobody will bother to check. `using namespace std;` is to be avoided.

Comment: Should be `HexStr( std::rbegin(data), std::rend(data) );` right?

Comment: Please change question name according to your note if it is not really the question you're asking.

Comment: > M.M.: Thanks, man! Please post your comment as the answer so I can close this ticket.

Answer (score 2):

`std::reverse_iterator` takes the original iterator type as template parameter.

Thus the type you're looking for is `const uint8_t*`, not `std::iterator<const uint8_t*>` (which is [another thing altogether](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator)).

Answer (score 2):

[`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is not what you think it is.

It's a base class made to simplify creation of iterator classes, and doesn't do anything by itself.
Also it was deprecated in C++17.

The code in your question *could* use `const uint8_t *` as an iterator, because [*it qualifies as one*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator),
but something tells me that `HexStr()` uses `++` to advance iterators, which is why wouldn't be able to use a pair of plain pointers to iterate backwards.